# How to expand an angular custom element which is shadow DOM in python selenium?

Tags: python, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 4 years of experience in Selenium, but I faced this kind of problem firstly.
I think only python selenium masters can solve this issue.
I used this function to get an Angular element, but it didn't work.

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome / chromedriver 96 and newer changed how interacting with Shadow DOM works. In order to interact with a Shadow DOM element with Selenium Python, you'll need to use a minimum of `selenium` version `4.1.0` or newer, and the method call you'll need to use is: `element.shadow_root`.

Additionally, there's a Selenium Python framework called SeleniumBase that can help simplify interactions with Shadow DOM elements. Here's an example test of that: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/shadow_root_test.py, which uses the SeleniumBase-specific `::shadow` selector to pierce through an element that contains one or more shadow root segments.